# Impedance problem (polar to rectangular)

Tags: ac, impedance

Having a little problem understanding why this example converted polar to rectangular form to get Z. What is wrong with just leaving it in polar form and doing the algebra to get the value for Z

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's semantics. If someone asked for an answer as impedance then I would tend to expect to see this answer in polar form. Converting to rectangular along the way is the simplest way of analysing the problem and converting back to polar at the end gives the answer as how I would expect it to be: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong at all.

If you did in polar form which is relatively tougher to do using hand calculation, it will yield the same result.

Therefore; If possible is it best to add and subtract in rectangular form and multiply and divide in rectangular form.